# Memory Management Confusion Objective C

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, xcode4

**Question 1**

```
Place *place = [[[Place alloc] initwithCoordinate:location anotationType:CSMapAnnotationTypeStart] autorealease];
place.name = name;
place.description = description;
place.strUniqueIdentity = uniqueIdentity;
NSLog(@"Unique identity %@",uniqueIdentity);

PlaceMark *marker = [[PlaceMark alloc] initWithPlace:place annotationType:MapAnnotationTypePin];
return [marker autorelease];
```

When i analyze the code in xcode 4.6.2 then it is showing 'Object sent -autorelease too many times' at second last line.
I can't understand why it is showing that.

[image: Screenshot 1]

**Question 2:**

```
return [[[OAProblem alloc] initWithResponseBody:response] autorelease];
```

And in this line it is showing "Potential leak of an object stored in 'self'".

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Why aren't you using `ARC`?

Comment: It seems correct, did you made some modification to memory management in the class itself like the initWithCoordinate or initWithPlace. Are sure there isn't something else in the scope you are showing?

Comment: @msgambel: I always use manual reference counting because it is better than ARC as specified by some persons.

Comment: Your code snippet is not the same as the screen grab.

Comment: @Yash: Couldn't disagree more. ARC sure has its edge cases and pitfalls, but in general ARC is better than MRC. Clang/llvm (usually) understands your code better than you do. As a result ARC-enabled code  is faster, cleaner, shorter and on average burns less brain cells than manual memory management would. Do yourself a favor.
You should definitely know MRC in and out (to understand ARC's edge cases), but you shouldn't use it these days, if possible.

Comment: @JeremyP: Thanks I edited that -autorealease call to first line.

Comment: @Regexident: ARC short's the code I agree about that but in the Big Projects as i read ARC is not as good as MRC.

Am i right? Please explain.

Comment: @Yash: Unless you have a concrete issue at hand there is absolutely no reason not to use ARC (you can always mark specific problematic files as MRC in your ARC project). ARC compiles down to MRC. Clang applies highly sophisticated algorithms to your code base in order to figure out where to optimally insert `retain`/`release`, omitting all the unnecessary ones (hence resulting in faster code). Right now **you appear to base your decision on pure speculation and hearsay**. ARC is there to help you. Use it. (Furthermore ARC enforces strict method naming conventions, which too, is a good thing.)

Comment: I use it if i am developing for iOS5+ compatible apps.
I know iOS4.0+ apps also support ARC Lite (without zeroing) but we use MRC for that.
Thanks for your explanation :)

Comment: @Yash the best check to see if there is a leak is use instruments with Memory Leak. I've seen different times the Analizer showing false positive, but in bigger and more complicated projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer of first part of my question is the small 'w' in the initialization method**

```
-initwithCoordinate: anotationType:
```

I have to use capital 'W' according to Cocoa naming conventions.

I replaced the initialization method with

```
-initWithCoordinate: anotationType:
```

**Answer of second part of my question is to add a [self release] in both the failure paths**

Xcode is being very unhelpful in it's analyser warning about OAProblem.c.

The code that's actually the problem is up in the init methods. The warning (in this case) means "an init method is returning nil without releasing the object allocated by alloc". The fix is to add a [self release] in both the failure paths:

```
- (id)initWithProblem:(NSString *) aProblem
{
    NSUInteger idx = [[OAProblem validProblems] indexOfObject:aProblem];
    if (idx == NSNotFound) {
        [self release]; // <-- Add this line to fix the warning
        return nil;
    }

    return [self initWithPointer: [[OAProblem validProblems] objectAtIndex:idx]];
}
```

and the same for initWithResponseBody.

Comment: Btw, "annotation" is spelled with two "n". ;)

Comment: Yes thats a typing mistake.
But i think that doesn't matter for naming conventions.

Answer (score 3):

The answer of `Why are you not using Arc?` is **completely invalid**. The OP is asking specially why is this happening in his own environment. So:

Can you show us your:

```
Place *place = [[Place alloc] initwithCoordinate:location anotationType:CSMapAnnotationTypeStart];
```

Also use instruments and see if there is a problem in fact with your project. Not everything that the static analyzer show is actually a problem. Some false positives might appear.

So from your response you have this:

```
 -(id)initwithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate anotationType:(CSMapAnnotationType)anotationType{ 
self.latitude = coordinate.latitude; 
self.longitude = coordinate.longitude; 
self.mapAnnotationType = anotationType; 
return self;
 }
```

It should be this:

```
-(id)initwithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate anotationType:(CSMapAnnotationType)anotationType{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        self.latitude = coordinate.latitude;
        self.longitude = coordinate.longitude;
        self.mapAnnotationType = anotationType;
    }
        return self;
}
```

That's why he is complaining about an object with retain count == 0.

Comment: First of thanks for the response.
The initialization is 

    -(id)initwithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate anotationType:(CSMapAnnotationType)anotationType{
    self.latitude = coordinate.latitude;
    self.longitude = coordinate.longitude;
    self.mapAnnotationType = anotationType;
    return self;
}

I think there is nothing related to Memory Management.

Comment: @JackyBoy: `init` does not retain the object, `alloc` does. `[Foo alloc]` returns an instance with retain count 1 (in theory, that is, at least) and hence so will `[[Foo alloc] init]`. Even if `init` is falsely defined as `- (id)init {return self;}`.

Comment: Its not the problem the problem is the lower case 'w' in method name.

Answer (score 2):

You get a warning because the spelling of `initwithCoordinate` is wrong. It should be `initWithCoordinate` (upper case W) according to Cocoa naming conventions.

Comment: @Yash The code in the second question looks OK. Do you still get the warning if you split it into two statements?

Comment: And you get one warning for each row?

Answer (score 1):

Xcode is being very unhelpful in it's analyser warning about OAProblem.c.

The code that's actually the problem is up in the init methods. The warning (in this case) means "an init method is returning nil without releasing the object allocated by alloc". The fix is to add a `[self release]` in both the failure paths:

```
- (id)initWithProblem:(NSString *) aProblem
{
    NSUInteger idx = [[OAProblem validProblems] indexOfObject:aProblem];
    if (idx == NSNotFound) {
        [self release]; // <-- Add this line to fix the warning
        return nil;
    }

    return [self initWithPointer: [[OAProblem validProblems] objectAtIndex:idx]];
}
```

and the same for `initWithResponseBody`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Place *place = [[Place alloc] initwithCoordinate:location anotationType:CSMapAnnotationTypeStart];
place.name = name;
place.description = description;
place.strUniqueIdentity = uniqueIdentity;
NSLog(@"Unique identity %@",uniqueIdentity);

PlaceMark *marker = [[PlaceMark alloc] initWithPlace:place    annotationType:MapAnnotationTypePin];
[place release];//I think you are release place object, cause of memory leak
return [marker autorelease];
```

Comment: autorelease releases the object at the autorealease pool not where it is called

I already tried this also.

Answer (score -2):

Better solution is converting your app to ARC(Automatic reference counting). It may take up the memory issue.

Take your xcode project Edit>Refactor>Convert to objective C ARC> OK

Comment: Why on earth everyone jumps up and shout ARC when someone post a memory management question? Friend, there are umpteen apps out there which are not using ARC and there are many developers who prefer to use manual memory management. And if you doesn't know, Manual memory management is still allowed.

Comment: For new code ARC is better, but this answer should be a comment on the question.

Comment: @JeremyP: What do you mean by new code and how it is better.
Please explain it.

Comment: @Yash:  if you are writing a project from scratch not using existing code that uses manual reference counting, ARC is better because it takes care of all this stuff automatically.

Comment: What stuff? It's because of saying things like that, people don't understand how you should actually handle memory. This is not GC... You can get into some pesky stuff if you are not careful.